Tools needed to repair carpet
My wife and I run a couple of rental houses for retirement income. In one of the the houses, I need to replace two small triangle-shaped staircase landings because of dog bites. I have some spare carpet in the garage. I called my regular carpet installers but they did not return my calls, apparently this is too small for their busy schedules.
I am planning to ask my general handyman who is a quick-learner and does not mind doing odd job to do it, but he does not have the tools. I plan to buy some simple carpet tools for my inventory of tools, because this damage is not uncommon. My properties are all in DFW, Texas. What simple tools do I have to buy? Thank you for your time.
PS. If you would like to include a link to a certain site, feel free giving me more than one to avoid apparent of promoting a certain product. Thank you again.


I laid carpet full time for two years.  For stairs, you need a knee kicker to stretch the carpet, a stair tool (looks like a chisel) to push the carpet into each horizonal corner as you go up the stairs, and a carpet knife.
You should get a wall tool to get an easy and consistent cut along with baseboards, but you can go without one if you are careful when you cut as you are tucking the edge under the baseboard.  The most expensive thing you need for stairs is an angled carpet stapler, though you might be able to get away without one if you tack strip in front of each riser. The chisel and the carpet stapler allow you to get really clean lines at each riser.

Thank you for your quick response. I think I know the knee kicker and chisel.  For angled stapler, can I rent it from Home  Depot? See the link below.  https://www.homedepot.com/p/rental/Roberts-Carpet-Stapler-10-600/316821394

That should work.  Kick. Chisel. Staple. Work way up the stairs.

Thank you for your pointers!

One more question, if you please: There are many sizes of steel staple out there, from 1/4" to 9/16". Which one do you use for carpet?

I think that depends on the gun you use.  Do you mean length?  Longer is going to be more hold.  You are going to probably fire a good 10 staples into every level.  IIRC, carpet staples are typically more narrow for stair applications.
